# How does Domain Driven Design handle Reporting?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I found DDD being natural if I am working on a operational/transactional type of application.  However I am always stucked in a reasonable way to handle reporting type of functions.

The reporting I am talking on is not bound to report generation, but also functions that perform comparatively complicated queries. (like, giving the summary of all orders that a trader did, or display the account summary for trading accounts having certain stock, etc).  They can be simply some query or supporting function that is used together with those operational function.

For such functions, it is quite natural if we can perform join in SQL (or whatever query language), get the columns we are interested, and return the massaged result set.  However, it seems such way not going that well with DDD: we need a extra special repository or having existing most-related repository returning a special "entity/value object" (which is the specialized resultset). These kind of special "entities" is not having any domain meaning in fact.

If we want to make use of the meaningful domain layer, that may creates a lot of extra lookups from different repository, plus a lot of aggregation work in the domain or service layer, which will easily cause horrible performance degrade.

I have also thought of having another "path" for these kind of function, which doesn't go through the "DDD path", having its own way to get the report data from DB, compose the results for display. However it is going to make the application unnecessarily complicated, and even worse, we provided an extra path so that developers that is more used to traditional DB-oriented development may tends to use this path even it is not appropriate.

I thought such situation is quite common (normally a big system will not contains operational but also reporting and enquiry functions), I would want to know how people is dealing with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently got into using DDD for system development. I had the same concerns as yours but eventually settled for Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) [Fowler, Young, Dahan]. While it is requires "the db path" for querying, I do not feel at all that it becomes tempting to do direct to DB for Commands (those that alter domain state). The separation is very clear - commands go through the domain, Queries go direct to DB.

Comment: Honestly it is hard to decide which one is correct but using CQRS seems most reasonable (and that's the most convincing response I get from domaindrivendesign.org too)

Answer (score 25):

In terms of DDD Reporting in most cases is a separate Bounded Context and a supporting subdomain where domain-driven design would be overkill. Remember the most important concept of DDD: Focus your modelling efforts on the Core Domain and implement everything else using the simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have a separate reporting system which ran data feeds from your app's data store to store another copy of the data in a more relational format.

A shortcut I've used is to create a view or stored procedure to return the joined data into a simple dumb object.

Comment: In fact the two suggestion you made is what I suggested in my original question.  I wish to have some clarifications or rationale in order to solve my worries.  And, just to emphasize again, the "reporting" I am talking on is not necessary to be a "report", but also some enquiry functions that is closely used with operational functions.

Answer (score 1):

> comparatively complicated queries. (like, giving the summary of all orders that a trader did, or display the account summary for trading accounts having certain stock, etc)

It is common for repositories to perform such tasks. I think you're worried about how to implement this efficiently, and the answer to that is "lazy loading".

For example, let's take "summary of all orders that a trader did". The "summary" is a reporting task, so let's put that aside. The domain task is "find all orders for a trader". You might have a repository method like this:

```
List<Order> findOrdersByTrader(Trader trader);
```

You can implement this by loading only the bare minimum (summary) information for each order. If you then inject the repository interface into the `Order` entity, the entity itself can call upon the repository to load additional sub-entities as and when required.

---

**Update:** Your comment makes the problem clearer -- I misunderstood the aggregation part earlier. It seems as though the "order summary" really belongs in your domain then. Sometimes it's not obvious that a concept is part of the domain, but if it's a feature that users talk about ("I want to view a summary of orders placed by this trader") and there isn't an existing object that can do this, that's a sign of a hidden concept in your domain. After all, you need *some* object to keep track of "how many orders for each stock" and there's no reason this object can't be part of your domain.

Comment: but that's what precisely I am worrying in my second alternative: make use of domain model and do the aggregations etc in domain /service layer.  For example, the function needs to tell how many orders for each stock a trader placed.  If we can do in query, it is probably a "comparatively complex" sql (not that complex though), with tens of result.  If we are getting all order entity of a trader and do aggregation ourselves, it is like getting thousands of record.  Performance difference is quite obvious (given I am still talking on a simplified case)